# mod_pagespeed does not compress, minify and optimize

Tags: apache, compression, mod-pagespeed

I have enabled the filters below with Mod_pagespeed, but when tested via PageSpeed Insights it recommends to "Enable Compression" for css resources, to "Minify CSS" and to "Optimize CSS":

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_heads
ModPagespeedEnableFilters defer_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
ModPagespeedEnableFilters make_google_analytics_async
ModPagespeedEnableFilters canonicalize_javascript_libraries
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
ModPagespeedEnableFilters elide_attributes
ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
ModPagespeedEnableFilters flatten_css_imports
ModPagespeedEnableFilters lazyload_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_import_to_link
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_jpeg_to_webp
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_google_font_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images
```

Subject site: http://goo.gl/vX8Dr4

At least for "Enable Compression" part, as far as I know the mod_pagespeed automatically activated mod_deflate for compression, doesn't it?

PS: PageSpeed Insights floats between 78 and 83 points without any changes to anything.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. As far as I can tell mod_deflate should be enabled but Pagespeed Insights reports that things aren't being gzipped as they should be...

Comment: I'm having the same issue,  the outputted mod_pagespeed assets do not seem to get mod_deflated